# PHP error checking in spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, warnings, autoload

I have a project which registers an autoloader using `spl_autoload_register()` that falls back to running `include_once()`.   If the file being loaded contains syntax errors, I want want to see errors logged normally, based on the current error reporting mode.  However, if my code includes a call to `class_exists('NoneSuch')`, I don’t want to see a warning.  I’m sure I’m missing something, but can’t work out how to achieve that.

Here’s a MWE using a file called `lib/Foo.pm` that contains a syntax error:

```php
<?php clsas Foo { }
```

And here's the main file:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
  $libdir = 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
  include_once("$libdir$path.php");
});

# This should not log a warning
class_exists('NoneSuch');

# This should report the syntax error in Foo.pm
new Foo;
```

I know I can prefix the call to `class_exists()` with an `@` to suppress warnings – that would be ideal – but many of these calls are in third-party code that I cannot edit.  Likewise, I know I can disable warnings with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNINGS)`, but many of the warnings PHP gives are useful.  If I prefix the `include_once()` with an `@`, then I lose the syntax errors in `Foo.pm` too.

I can’t easily wrap the `include_once()` in an `if (file_exists("...")) {}` because that doesn’t respect include paths, and I can’t easily use the default `spl_autoload()` function because that won’t know about by `$libdir` variable.  I don't particularly want to append `$libdir` to the include path, because I don't want these files to be loadable by `include()` other than via the autoloader because the actual autoloader does quite a bit more for debugging, profiling and making legacy class aliases that isn't included in this MWE, and I don't want these being accidentally bypassed.

Is there any way of telling whether the autoloader function is being called by a `class_exists()` call?

Comment: Is it this TYPO `<?php clsas Foo { }` causing the problem?

Comment: How often are you expecting syntax errors in code invoked via `class_exists`?

Comment: Further, is your system pluggable that you need `class_exists` in the first place? I ask because I rarely have a need for it personally, regardless of the complexity of my system

Comment: I’m not 100% clear on your second to last paragraph, but if you call [`set_include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php), it will return the old path, so you could append `$libdir`, `include` and then reset it

Comment: @ChrisHaas – Many of the libraries loaded this way are under active development, so, yes, errors do happen.  Syntax errors are rare, but other errors such as calls to non-existent functions do happen.  They're (hopefully) caught during testing, but the code is hard to debug if errors in my own libraries are hidden.  We don't use `class_exists()` in our code at all, but some third-party libraries do, including PHPUnit which we use heavily for testing.  Getting lots of warnings from it makes it hard to spot the genuine warnings.

Comment: @ChrisHaas – Regarding setting up the include path manually, that is possible, but it means picking apart the existing path, appending `$libdir` to each component, and joining them up again.  (Often it'll be something like `..:../..`.)  That seems rather messy, but, yes, it does work.

Comment: I don’t think you need to do any path picking apart, just backup, either prepend/append, include, and restore: https://3v4l.org/s4T17

Comment: @ChrisHaas – Perhaps I didn't explain myself very well.  The point is that `$libdir` is relative to the include path, so if the include path is `..:../..` and `$libdir` is `lib`, then I need to try both `../lib` and `../../lib`.

Comment: Based on your comments, I think the short answer is no, you can’t have everything you want above. My recommendation is to use the `@` trick along with `error_get_last()` and do something custom. It sounds like this isn’t a problem in production, so you should hopefully be able to constrain things to known environments